# Qt widgets use resources included by msvc 2015

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to use resources included by MSVC in Qt widgets?
For example to load QIcon from PNG included as RCDATA.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

Comment: @Drop note that I don't use Qt Creator. So I can't use standard Qt resource system.

Comment: You do not need the creator to use the resource system!

Comment: @Mailerdaimon compare standard resource system and that used by Qt. It is not the same.

Comment: I did not say that it is the same, I said that you can use the qt resource system without qt creator

Comment: @Mailerdaimon ok now I see. Could you give me any tutorial?

Comment: Drop already gave you the link to the documentation. Should be enough to get it going.

Comment: There is no info about std resource system in Drop's link. I would not post question if I could find answer in docs